# Getting backing field name of a property

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties

Might be a duplicate but I couldn't find a way to properly formulate what I was looking for.

Is there a way to get the name of the backing field returned by a property using the property itself or an extension?

```
private string VariableNameToGet;
public string TheProperty {get => VariableNameToGet; set {VariableNameToGet = value;}}
```

In other words, would there be a way to end up with something like `TheProperty.GetPrivateVariableName()` that would return `"VariableNameToGet"` in a generic way?

Comment: Not in an easy way. The question is: Why do you need it? (one way is to drill down into the property get method (get_TheProperty) and extract this information. But those can be complex and may not actually only be return X;). What do you actually want to do?

Comment: You're looking for what's called the backing field.  I'm not sure about whether you can, though.

Comment: properties are just syntax for getter and setter methods, meaning that they don't have to have actual backing fields.  They could just return constant values.  So there's no point in doing something generic.  It would make more sense to just expose the name of that field if you need it for some reason.

Comment: @DennisKuypers I was mostly curious to know if it was possible since I'm not to familiar with deep reflection stuff and "low level c#". I currently have a workaround for the problem. So I would say personnal knowledge mostly.

Comment: As an aside, you may also have auto properties that don't even have a backing field. For example: `public string TheProperty { get; set; }`. What you're asking doesn't really make any sense I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG they do have backing fields. But those are compiler generated.

Comment: @BiesiGrr Yes I know, but the implication is that you care even less about them. After all who is really bothered about the field `<TheProperty>k__BackingField`?

Comment: @DennisKuypers can we claim it is impossible without inspecting getter's and setter's bytecode?

Comment: We can at least say that reflection is required, I suppose

Answer (score 2):

You can get field info with [`Module.ResolveMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.module.resolvemember) method

Let's assume we need to get `System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute.Browsable`'s backing field

```cs
// get property info
PropertyInfo property = typeof(BrowsableAttribute).GetProperty("Browsabe");

// Need getter, because setter is missing
MethodInfo getter = property.GetGetMethod();

// Now we should get MSIL bytes stream that represents operations
byte[] bytes = getter.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

/* IL looks like this
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldfld bool System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute::'<Browsable>k__BackingField'
IL_0006: ret
*/

// Knowing that field token is Int32 and it's located at offset=2 we can get it
int fieldReference = BitConvert.ToInt32(bytes, 2);

// Last part is to get actual FieldInfo
var field = (FieldInfo)property.DeclaringType.Module.ResolveMember(fieldReference);

// Now we have access to field's backing field!
Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
```

This solution is far from perfect: It assumes that property is generated by Roslyn compiler and auto-implemented properties is used. If someone has implemented property manually we potentially can crush, because code size should be 7. May break in future version of runtime or not work in previous versions (I've tested on net5)

Better solution would be usage of Mono.Cecil, but I've never tried it.